# How to fetch only latest/first version of each array condition using whereIn Laravel query builder method

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have 2 models in my Laravel project: User and Field, they are connected with Many to Many relationship.

Field model have only 2 columns: slug, data and timestamps.
I want to get Users with some fields by slug, but not all of them but only the latest ones for each of slug from an array.

Here what I'm trying to do:

This code example will fetch all fields related to `User id:1` and have `slug` from $slugs array.

```php
$slugs = ['first_name','last_name'];
User::with(['fields' => function($query) {
    $query->whereIn('slug', $slugs);
}])->find(1);
```

But each User can have lots of fields with the same slug - let's call this field versions. 
So User 1 actually have field 
`[slug => first_name, data => John]` and also `[slug => first_name, data => Mary]`. I want to fetch only latest field version for each slug from `$slugs` array.

This is incorrect example, but that's what return only latest version for first field slug found in db.

```php
$slugs = ['first_name','last_name'];
User::with(['fields' => function($query) {
    $query->whereIn('slug', $slugs)->latest()->first();
}])->find(1);
```

Is there any way to do this using query builder?

Comment: I think you are almost correct. don't call `first()` just `$query->whereIn('slug', $slugs)->latest()`. Try.

Comment: `latest()` will just order results, but will return all field versions. I need to fetch only 1 field per slug from whereIn $slugs array...

Comment: if you only want one then call `latest()->take(1)`. never call `first()`

Comment: latest()->take(1) inside whereIn() method will stop when 1 item will be found. I need to take 1 of each of field types from $slugs array